# alternate merge linked list (c code)

Tags: c

Sample outcome:

Given 2 linked list:

> LL1: 1 3 5 7 9
>
> LL2: 2 4 6

After running program, the result should be ...

Result:

> LL1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
>
> LL2: empty

Something is wrong with the below code.

```
void alternateMergeLinkedList(LinkedList *ll1, LinkedList *ll2)
{
    /* add your code here */
    int index = 1;
    int j;

    ListNode *ptr_node1;
    ListNode *ptr_node2;

    ptr_node1 = ll1->head;
    ptr_node2 = ll2->head;

    while (ptr_node2 != NULL) {
        j = insertNode(ll1, index, ptr_node2->item);
        j = removeNode(ll2, 0);
        index += 2;
    }
}
```

Given insertNode and removeNode functions:

```
int insertNode(LinkedList *ll, int index, int value)
{

    ListNode *pre, *cur;

    if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index > ll->size + 1)
        return -1;

    // If empty list or inserting first node, need to update head pointer
    if (ll->head == NULL || index == 0) {
        cur = ll->head;
        ll->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        ll->head->item = value;
        ll->head->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }

    // Find the nodes before and at the target position
    // Create a new node and reconnect the links
    if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {
        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        pre->next->item = value;
        pre->next->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}


int removeNode(LinkedList *ll, int index)
{

    ListNode *pre, *cur;

    // Highest index we can remove is size-1
    if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index >= ll->size)
        return -1;

    // If removing first node, need to update head pointer
    if (index == 0) {
        cur = ll->head->next;
        free(ll->head);
        ll->head = cur;
        ll->size--;

        return 0;
    }

    // Find the nodes before and after the target position
    // Free the target node and reconnect the links
    if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {

        if (pre->next == NULL)
            return -1;

        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        ll->size--;
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Try to step through the code, line by line, in a debugger, to see what it actually does.

Comment: Also in your `alternateMergeLinkedList` function, that `index += 2` might not be so good when `ll2` is longer than `ll1`.

Comment: Finally, you have shown us the expected result, but what is the *actual* results? How do you get that result? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1. I am not sure why it does not exit the while loop in `alternateMergeLinkedList`. For each iteration, node at index 0 should be removed until the head is pointed to NULL.

2. For `index += 2`, I can compare the size of each linked list and find the number of loops then use 'for' instead of 'while'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `ptr_node2` once before the loop, and that's it. If you do no update it in the loop it will not change.

A better loop condition might be `while (ll2->size > 0)`.

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem of infinite loop.  
However, the result is not what we are expected.

input:  
LL1: 1 3 5  
LL2: 2 4  
  
output:  
LL1: 1 2 3 -572662307 5  
LL2: Empty  
  
There is something wrong with the second iteration.